# Set select for a <p> in Javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a example code here (from w3schools):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the button to copy the text from the text field. Try to paste the text (e.g. ctrl+v) afterwards in a different window, to see the effect.</p>

<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  
  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It will select the input:
[image]

But i when to select a `<p>` tag like this:
[image]
Thanks for help!